# How to organize routing in API-based multipage client-side application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, web-applications

I have significant experience building Ruby on Rails applications. But I've never done API-based applications. Recently I've learnt Knockout pretty well, and thus I know how to organize my client-side application if it is single page (SPA).

The problem I have: I don't know how to manage communication between pages if I have API-based multipage (!) application. Of cause I can hardcode all the links in my pages, but it may quickly become unmanageble if I decide to change something. I would like to have some kind of router on the client-side. Do you know about framework, or do you have idea how to organize all the routing?

Comment: There's a lot of options for a [javascript router](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20router) out there. But I'm not sure what this has to do with being a "API based" application. Are you looking for a recommendation for a router or are you having trouble organizing your project with routing in mind? Please provide some more detail.

Comment: Say, I have project management application built on top of Trello. It has existing API. In my application I would have page for all projects, page for one project, page for user etc. If I crate a single page application (SPA), I can use any router you've specified, or framework like  Ember.js, Backbone.js (which have their own routers). But I don't how to deal with the routing, if I decide to keep those pages isolated (with their own real url and usual page reload when moving from page to page).

Comment: Well that would be serverside routing then, handled by your Rails app. Are you asking how to get server side route generation on the client side? Like how rails lets you do `order_path(@order)` to generate the path `/orders/123`?

Comment: No, my problem is: I don't have Rails-application. The only thing I have is API (which I cannot change), and it responds to my requests with JSON. I would like to build application page by page (i.e. separate html file with its own js-model for projects, page for project, page for user etc.). I don't see a convenient way to manage all the cross-links between my pages. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PagerJS http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/start is a routing framework built for Knockout. This should handle your single page needs.

In case you were referring to keeping your app in sync with the API resources:

We have the *api/user* endpoint. Then create an object accessible to the whole application that manages all the actions referring to users. Something like

```
var userUrl = 'api/url'
var userResource = {
    get: function(callback){
        http.get(userUrl, function(err,data){
            callback(data);
        });
    },
    save: function(user, callback){
        http.put(userUrl, function(err, data){
            //...
        });   
    },
//... and so on
```

This way you won't have the API url referred all around the application but only in the user resource.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern used in the Microsoft Knockout SPA template takes care of most of your requirements.  This is their viewmodel structure:

```
Login    AnotherPage    EtcPage
|_____________|____________|
              |
             App
              |
            Data
```

The "Data" level is where you have all of your api calls and/or local storage/WebSQL/IndexedDB stuff.  You can also store site-wide persistent data in Knockout observables there for easy cross-page access.

The "App" level has all site-wide view info, like menu/header actions.  Since the App viewmodel is always loaded its a good place to deal with navigation.

The top level viewmodels contain code only found those individual pages (Login, etc).  They all have the App and Data viewmodels passed to them as arguments to their constructors:

```
var LoginViewModel = function(app, dataModel){
  var self = this;
  // etc...
}
```

Now for routing:
The gist of how the Microsoft template deals with routing by keeping a list of the view models, then assigns the the current view model based on a link click. I really didn't like that approach.

I've used [Finch.js](http://stoodder.github.io/finchjs) for routing in this situation.  Its very easy to use, but the documentation is in coffeescript which is an annoyance. While Finch does offer ways of passing parameters between pages, it's redundant in this case.